# Differentation on time scales

Tags: derivatives

Find $g^\Delta$ from definition where $g(t)=\sqrt{t}$.

Definition: $f^\Delta(t)$ is such number, that for every $\varepsilon>0$ neighbourhood $U_t$ of $t$ exists that $|f(\sigma(t))-f(s)-f^\Delta(t)(\sigma(t)-s)|\leq\varepsilon|\sigma(t)-s|$ for every $s\in U_t$

I know that the answer is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}+\sqrt{\sigma(t)}}$, but don't know how to get it.

What I have:
$|f(\sigma(t))-f(s)-f^\Delta(t)(\sigma(t)-s)|=|\sqrt{\sigma(t)}-f^\Delta(t)(\sigma(t)-s)|\\=|(\sigma(t)-s)(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sigma(t)}+\sqrt{s})})-f^\Delta(t)(\sigma(t)-s)|\\=|(\sigma(t)-s)(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sigma(t)}+\sqrt{s})}-f^\Delta(t))|$

What do I do next?

Comment: What is $\sigma$?

Answer (score 0):

You already did almost everything: the neighborhood contains $t$ and so you can take $s=t$, which forces $f^\Delta$ to be the expression that you wrote (otherwise you cannot make it less than some $\varepsilon$).

PS: Notice that you forgot the term $\sqrt s$ in the line "What I have...".